# Find uppercase letters with one lowercase letter between them

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

What regular expression do I need to find 3 uppercase letters with 1 lowercase letter between them?

For example, I have: `sDdDSADadasAHHdHSAsdsagfGoHHHfHHHH`

But I need: `AHHdHSA`

I'm new to regular expressions but something like `[A-Z]{3}[a-z]{1}[A-Z]{3}` will find also `HHHfHHH`, but I only need 3 uppercase and the next one need to be lowercase. I need to get `AHHdHSA`.

Comment: Why should it not match `HHHfHHH`?

Comment: How is HHHfHHH not also a match

Comment: guys, in HHHfHHHH we have 4 uppercases, I need to have only 3 between the 1 lowercase. So like this: AAAbAAAcDe -> AAAbAAA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert not an uppercase char before and after the 3 uppercase chars.

```
(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}(?![A-Z])
```

- `(?<![A-Z])` Negative lookbehind, assert no upppercase char on the left
- `[A-Z]{3}` Match 3 uppercase chars A-Z
- `[a-z]` Match a single lowercase char (note that you can omit the `{1}`)
- `[A-Z]{3}` Match 3 uppercase chars
- `(?![A-Z])` Negative lookahead, assert no uppercase char on the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qks5ym/1)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe,

```
(?<=[^A-Z]|^)[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}(?=[^A-Z]|$)
```

would do then.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QE35Dn/1/)

---

I guess to implement this pattern, we might want to have the `regex` module installed,

```
$ pip3 install regex
```

Otherwise, I think, the pattern [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58827308/6553328) would be a better choice, which you can implement it with `re` module:

```
import re

string = '''
sDdDSADadasAHHdHSAsdsagfGoHHHfHHHH
AHHdHSA
'''

expression = r'(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}(?![A-Z])'

print(re.findall(expression, string))
```

#### Test

```
import regex as re

string = '''
sDdDSADadasAHHdHSAsdsagfGoHHHfHHHH
AHHdHSA
'''

expression = r'(?<=[^A-Z]|^)[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}(?=[^A-Z]|$)'

print(re.findall(expression, string))
```

#### Output

```
['AHHdHSA', 'AHHdHSA']
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/QE35Dn/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/QE35Dn/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use groups to ensure that you grab the pattern while also matching around it:

```
# to match your pattern with a lowercase letter after
pat1 = re.compile('([A-Z]{3}[a-z]{1}[A-Z]{3})([a-z]+)')

# should yield what you need
pat1.search('sDdDSADadasAHHdHSAsdsagfGoHHHfHHHH').group(1)

# as an explanation for group capture, run this:
mymatch = pat1.search('sDdDSADadasAHHdHSAsdsagfGoHHHfHHHH')
mymatch.group(0)
mymatch.group(1)
mymatch.group(2)
```